# HTML Email parser for safe HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, email

Before i spend time trying to reinvent the wheel. My web application receives inbound emails from users. Most typically these are received as HTML encoded. I need to be able to display these to the users in a somewhat friendly format.

Is there anything that exists that will do most of the grunt work on this? I was looking for a package i just pass in my raw HTML email and it will strip and format it for display.

Short of anything already out there, specifically, i could use something to strip out the tag: https://github.com/punkave/sanitize-html

I'd rather not use iframes, and just add it to the DOM inside a div placeholder. My concerns are:

- Strip all JS in the message
- Remove any tags that could contain an external reference
- Remove all CSS

The allowed tags would be fairly basic: p, b, i, strong, br; eg stuff so that it looks like a message not a bunch of hard to read text.

What have you done for this in the past?

Comment: You should probably mention which programming language you are using server side.

Comment: @moritz using vb .net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will save someone else some time that is having a similar problem:

On the user side, inside the div where you want to show the email message:

```
<iframe src="/view/message/{message_id}" sandbox></iframe>
```

The iframe route just displays the HTML, then i used a github library: https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer to strip all the CSS tags, and most HTML tags. I left basic formatting tags P; BR; B. I also stripped all javascript as well.